# Workflow Foundation in .NET 4.0 tracking execution

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

Please help, i am developing a POC in Windows Workflow Foundation under .NET 4.0, i have to have good/interesting features in this. Trying to put tracking of the workflow execution (which tells visually about the completion/pending activities). i am unable to get the right link.

Samples or links would be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EtwTrackingParticipant will let you track events and put them in the Windows event log. When you are hosting your workflows in IIS7 or above you can also use the AppFabric to monitor workflow execution. If you create your own based on TrackingParticipant tou can track it any way you like.